# Adding numbers to 2-d array based on index

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of size 21:

```
arr1
array([  0., 329., 730., 513.,   0., 167.,   0.,   0., 175.,   0., 220.,
         0.,   0.,   0., 202.,   0.,   0.,  59.,   0.,  33.,  47.])
```

I have an indexed array of size 21:

```
arg_arr
array([4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 0, 3],
      dtype=int64)
```

I need add the elements to a numpy array of zeros of size 5 based on their index. i.e. at index 0, the output arr2 =  0 + 0 + 202 + 33.

```
arr2 = np.zeros((5,))
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

How can I do this with numpy?

Comment: Why does your title mention 2D?

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook usecase for `np.add.at`:

```
np.add.at(arr2, arg_arr, arr1)
```

The special thing about [`ufunc.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) vs just doing `arr2[arg_arr] += arr1` is that the operation is unbuffered, so multiple occurrences of an index are handled correctly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you